# Move character while all other objects are paused

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I want to make a mechanic in unity like matrix but instead of that, the time is absolutely paused excepting the player when I press a key, and when I press it again the object's time get back to normal. I want that the rigidbody don't get slowed. It's like the Bend Time power in Dishonored

I'm new in this, so I don't know how to make a unique object have its normal time and the others to be paused, I only tried to set Time.timeScale to 0, but obviously it affected all the objects.

Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Stopping the time works well with `Time.timeScale` as you did and for your player, you would then use `Time.unscaledDeltaTime` to calculate it's movement (e.g. with `CharacterController.Move()` in `Update()`), same for e.g. the attached camera so that it still follows the player etc. .

While time is frozen (timeScale = 0), you'd need to handle the movement for objects yourself as the physics system is also stopped. This could be very difficult for complex physics simulations (like collision responses), but 'quite' straightforward for simple object or character/camera movement and simple collision checks. For the latter you can work with [Physics.SphereCast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.SphereCast.html) and the like to create a continuous collision detection.